# Reuseable function component incorrect callback

Tags: reactjs

I've created a very simple reuseable file upload component. I use it twice in my project however the callback that is called 'onChange' is incorrect for e.g. it is calling the function from the second usage not the first.

I was initially using refs, so I moved the ref upto the parent component passed it to the child via forwardRef and set the onChange to monitor the files array length of the element and when it changes run the callback function. But this resulted in the same issue.

```
const FileUpload = ({ file, className, children, text }) => {
  const handleChange = e => {
    if (
      e.currentTarget.files.length > 0 &&
      e.currentTarget.files[0].type.split("/")[0] === "image"
    ) {
      file(
        e.currentTarget.files[0],
        e.currentTarget.files[0].name.split(".")[1]
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <Label htmlFor="file" className={className}>
      {children}
      {text}
      <Input type="file" onChange={handleChange} id="file" name="file" />
    </Label>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;

<FileUpload file={handleFile} text="Upload Image" />
```

The 'file' callback is executed 'onChange' however it is the incorrect instance, I's calling the function from the second usage of the component instead of the first.

Comment: This may not be related to your problem but I wouldn't use a fixed id inside a reusable component, i.e. `id="file"`

Comment: you can pass the parent props to the child via `...this.props`
Now it should become `<FileUpload file={handleFile} text="Upload Image" ...this.props />`

Comment: @ArianKhosravi That was indeed the issue, Cannot believe this did not occur to me before. Should've been obvious never have duplicate id's in the DOM. I was using the id on the input for the 'htmlFor' on the label as I have a the label styled as a button for opning the browse dialog to select file. I have now made this dynamic and passed it as a prop so the id's are different on each use.

Comment: @MuhammadZia Wouldn't that syntax be for a class component, would be simply ...props for a function component. I like explicitly stating my props so components are passed only what is relevant to them.

Comment: @M1ke sorry about that, for a functional component it'll be ...props, I am currently working on a project that has classes, so many a times a miss it out.

Comment: @M1ke glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was the id's I had fixed values for the id's, This in turn meant when using the component more than once there would be duplicate id's in the DOM. The htmlFor attribute on the label would activate the browse dialog for the file input but due to there being two inputs with identical id's the wrong one is activated.

Fix: Set id's dynamically, in my case I added a 'uid' prop and passed a value from the parent each time I used the component. It now works as expected.

Thanks to @ArianKhosravi for pointing me in the right direction.